# Convert JSON containing geometry to postgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, postgis

I have a JSON file that contains the attribute of several parks along with location (geometry) as a point. I was wondering how to convert the JSON to postgreSQL format. Indeed, I have tried several ways such as SQLizer and MapForce, but I was not able to convert them. Is there any way to convert this JSON which has geometry, to postgreSQL format?

I appreciate any help.

Below you can find the script.

```js
var lenneparks = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "place": "Aachen Kurpark",
        "year": "1853 (Hi)",
        "text": "Elisengarten, kleine Parkanlage in der Innenstadt, rückwärtig vom Elisenbrunnen"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.086027,
          50.774247
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "place": "Aachen",
        "year": "ca. 1862 (Hi)",
        "text": "Staatsprokurator Dubusc"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.0838868,
          50.7653455
        ]
      }
    }
      ]
};
```

Comment: Please share one of the ways you have tried and what errors you received.

Comment: I tried it with  SQLizer ( https://sqlizer.io/#/ ) and Altova MapForce. 

in sqlizer the error was that, "your JSON file is invalid " i think that error was because of the inability  of the converter to convert GeoJSON. 
and in mapforce I could not fine any extention or module for Geojson

Comment: it helps when you share what the error was from those attempts.

Comment: Cleaned up some grammar and spelling. Clarified postgreSQL. Changed wording to be more natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 1**: Corrected SQL comments

Have you tried the PostGIS extension? It comes with really handy functions to import such data, such as:

```
-- To create a geometry object from your GeoJSON
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}') As geometry;

-- To see the WKT of your GeoJSON
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}')) As geometry;
```

**EDIT 2**: Creating records for each geometry

This function will create a table containing one record for each json element in the array `features`, from there you can start parsing the data you need for creating your tables... I hope it helps:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE features AS 
SELECT json_array_elements('{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "place": "Aachen Kurpark",
        "year": "1853 (Hi)",
        "text": "Elisengarten, kleine Parkanlage in der Innenstadt, rückwärtig vom Elisenbrunnen"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.086027,
          50.774247
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "place": "Aachen",
        "year": "ca. 1862 (Hi)",
        "text": "Staatsprokurator Dubusc"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.0838868,
          50.7653455
        ]
      }
    }
      ]
}'::JSON -> 'features') as features;


SELECT * FROM features;
```

**EDIT 3**: Query to extract info from json table

```
SELECT 
  features -> 'geometry' -> 'coordinates' -> 0 AS lat,
  features -> 'geometry' -> 'coordinates' -> 1 AS lon,
  features -> 'properties' -> 'place'::TEXT,
  features -> 'properties' -> 'year'::TEXT,
  features -> 'properties' -> 'text'::TEXT
  FROM features;
```

**EDIT 4**: Extracting geometries from the json table and converting them into WKT and Geometry

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON((features -> 'geometry')::text)
FROM features;  

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON((features -> 'geometry')::TEXT))
FROM features;
```

Comment: Actually I did not try it with this extension. Thanks for your hint. 

But I wanted to ask you that, How can I convert them to SQL format with geoJSON ?
because i want to develop this database. Therefore it is much more convenient for me to work on the SQL format .

Comment: Maybe I'm not following what you mean by `SQL format`. These functions I mentioned above do exactly that. They read GeoJSON and create a geometry / wkt literal. If you're only dealing with points, you can store the coordinates as `NUMERIC` and do your operations, but I strongly suggest you to use PostGIS for this matter and store them as `GEOMETRY`. It's infinitely easier to use, the installation is very straightforward, and it has a huge community support.

Comment: btw, if you're planing to publish your geometries using a WFS, you will need postgis anyway.

Comment: Many thanks Jim  for your effort. it helps me a lot.